# what approch will be robust to pop the files of USB device as it is connected to ANDROID device

Tags: android, usb, explorer

what approch will be robust to get a popup window containing the files of USB device as it is connected to ANDROID device, means pending intent or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout out the [USB host API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) that is available in the android 3.1 and above..